# How screenWidthDp and densityDpi get calculated?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two devices, Samsung Tab 4 and Samsung J Max. Screen size and resolutions are same (Screen Size : 7"
Resolution : 800x1280) but when i run following code its returning different values.

```
Configuration configuration = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
        int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp;
        int densityDPI =  configuration.densityDpi;
```

**Samsung Tab 4** 
 screenWidthDp = 600
densityDPI = 213

**Samsung J Max**
 screenWidthDp = 533
densityDPI = 240

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer decides the density setting of the screen of the devices. Usually it tries to align that setting  to predefined density buckets (**hdpi** or **tvdpi** for example).

The major difference here is that the J Max is sold as a large phone while the Tab 4 is a tablet. In the Android developers documentation there is some consensus that the definition of a tablet is a device with a screen whose smallest width is at least 600dp (think of `layout-sw600dp` resources folder).

So for the Tab 4 Samsung chose to use the tvdpi density bucket, in order for the screen space to reach a smallest width of 600dp, thus apps will work in tablet mode when available. For the large phone they chose a density bucket of hdpi so the smallest width of the screen is right below 600dp at 533dp so apps will still display in phone mode.